# How can I write a do loop as a table?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a do loop that looks like this:

```
Do[a = -1; b = 1; c = n; d = a + b + c; Print[d], {n, 1, 12}]
```

which gives the output:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9
>
> 10
>
> 11
>
> 12

How can I write the Do loop as a Table while preserving the program structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as this simple question was answered by the poser, I might as well fine tune it:

```
Table[a = -1; b = 1; a + b + n, {n, 12}]
```

or more efficient:

```
a = -1; b = 1; Table[a + b + n, {n, 12}]
```

Comment: Even more efficient: `a = -1; b = 1; a + b + Range[12]`

Answer (score 4):

While I like [David's simplification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72141/52), this can be taken further. As pointed out in a number of places, `Table` is inefficient both time-wise and space-wise, so it can often be replaced, especially in this case.

```
a + b + Range[12]
(*{1 + a + b, 2 + a + b, 3 + a + b, 4 + a + b, 5 + a + b, 6 + a + b, 
   7 + a + b, 8 + a + b, 9 + a + b, 10 + a + b, 11 + a + b, 12 + a + b}*)
```

As you can see, `a + b` was automatically threaded through the list, and when `a` and `b` have numeric values, the list remains packed and takes up less space then a general list does.

Comment: Yep.  Even simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I really, really should have read the [comments](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72138/how-can-i-write-a-do-loop-as-a-table#comment197728_72138) first. But, he doesn't need any points anymore. :)

Comment: You are perfectly correct in your answer. But I now realize that I stated the question too simply. Let us say you have a more specific situation like calculating the eigenvalues of some complicated matrix. In that case adding a Range to the variables will not do the job. But again, because of the way I stated my question you are correct.

Comment: @MatsGranvik that's why I prefaced my statement with "in this case," as it is often not the case that this can be done. :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to remove the Print statement and let the line d = a + b + c be the output:

```
Table[a = -1; b = 1; c = n; d = a + b + c, {n, 1, 12}]
```

Output:

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}